# ImportError: No module named south.v2 but I don't use south

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-south

I am running django 1.9 on a newly installed lubuntu 16.04.  I created a virtual environment and cloned my repository from github.  I try to run `./manage.py runserver` and I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named south.v2
```

I've checked other similar questions, but they seem to imply that I am upgrading from south, which I haven't used for years, and never on this repository.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jcg/.virtualenvs/baseball/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jcg/.virtualenvs/baseball/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/home/jcg/.virtualenvs/baseball/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 163, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/home/jcg/.virtualenvs/baseball/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/jcg/.virtualenvs/baseball/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/jcg/.virtualenvs/baseball/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 170, in build_graph
    self.load_disk()
  File "/home/jcg/.virtualenvs/baseball/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 105, in load_disk
    migration_module = import_module("%s.%s" % (module_name, migration_name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/jcg/.virtualenvs/baseball/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions/migrations/0001_empty.py", line 2, in <module>
    from south.v2 import SchemaMigration
ImportError: No module named south.v2
```

Here is my pip freeze results:

```
chardet==2.2.1
Django==1.9.2
django-appconf==0.6
django-bootstrap3==6.2.2
django-csvimport==1.0
django-debug-toolbar==1.4
django-extensions==1.5.0
docutils==0.12
gunicorn==19.4.5
Markdown==2.6.5
Pygments==2.1.1
six==1.7.3
sqlparse==0.1.18
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman -- just posted traceback

Comment: It's obvious from the trackback that you were using package `django_extensions` and they happened to be using `south`(check last file).

Comment: I wasn't aware of that.  i've used it before and never got this error.  So you think if I remove django_extensions, it will work?

Comment: Or, you could just install `south`.

Comment: I upgraded django-extensions to django_extensions-1.6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl . Problem solved.  @MattDMo

Comment: It looks like you are using an old version of django_extensions; the version in github includes south migrations but doesn't rely on them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update you django-extension to the newest version 1.6.7:

```
pip install django-extensions==1.6.7
```

This old version uses the south for migrations while the new one uses the default migrations from django, which were introduced in version 1.6

Comment: I realized this, but for the usefulness to others, thanks